# Bringing PyQt and PyChart together

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pychart

I want to visualize some measurement values in realtime. I think - although not finally sure - I can do this with PyChart. The surrounding application is based on PyQt.

Now I', wondering how I can put the chart drawn using PyChart into some qt widget, may be a QGraphicWidget?

Could someone give me a bit advise?

Cheers,
Wolfgang

Answer (score 0):

I have learned to do this by following the instructions of Eli Benderski.

It is answered here on this site [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972158/how-to-plot-on-my-gui-from-pyqt)

Demo Code is [here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/files/prog_code/qt_mpl_bars.py.txt)

This uses matplotlib instead of PyChart. Usage of matplotlib is well documented [here](http://matplotlib.org/contents.html).

Matplotlib allows you to interact with the plot canvas as well as importing a Navigation Tool Bar.

Hope this is helpful.